# Firestore updates using python api are not persisting

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have the following code.

```
from firebase_admin import firestore

db = firestore.client()
collection = db.collection('word_lists')
word_list = collection.get()

for item in word_list:
    item_dict = item.to_dict()
    print item_dict['next_practice_date']
    item.reference.update({'next_practice_date': 0.0})
```

When I run the code the first time everything is fine, no errors. The second time I run it I expect all the prints to print `0.0` but instead many print `None`, particularly the ones at the end. What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find the solution to the problem but instead switched `from firebase_admin import firestore`

to `from google.cloud import firestore` and everything works well now.

Answer (score 0):

```
from firebase_admin import firestore

db = firestore.client()
collection = db.collection('word_lists')
word_list = collection.get()

if not word_list.exists(): return
for item in word_list:
    item_dict = item.to_dict()
    print(item_dict['next_practice_date'])
    item.reference.update({'next_practice_date': 0.0})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).